# References about abelian group theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups

Perhaps the most famous book about abelian group theory is Fuchs' *Infinite Abelian Groups*, which was published in 1970. Is this book (still) the standard reference or is it outdated? What are some more recent references on abelian group theory?

Comment: See `An Introduction to the Theory of Groups` by `Joseph J. Rotman`

Comment: There is also *Infinite Abelian Groups* by Irving Kaplansky, but it is older than Fuchs' book.